# add widget to page content (using shortcode)

Tags: shortcode, widgets

I'd like to be able to add a custom widget (that a site's previous web developer built) to the Wordpress page content, ideally using shortcode.

I've searched for how to add a widget to a page, but the results I find point to [amr shortcode any widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amr-shortcode-any-widget/) which is 7 months old.

I'd like to add the shortcode into my child theme's `functions.php`.

Can this be done? If so, help appreciated.

Comment: Could this be what you need? https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-shortcode/

Comment: An an answer if you like @danbrellis.